# eosio 1.5.1 - keosd & produces: Application does have a valid signature

Tags: nodeos, eosio.token, keosd, blockchains

Following the eosio website I install eosio with brew.

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/getting-the-software

The first step after the install is to run `keosd &`.
I get the following output:

```
    **Application does not have a valid signature; Secure Enclave support** disabled info
   ~ » keosd &                                                                                                                                                                                                       
   shawnrmoss@Hex
    [1] 1890
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.679 thread-0  wallet_plugin.cpp:42          plugin_initialize    ] initializing wallet plugin
    warn  2019-01-15T18:38:20.681 thread-0  se_wallet.cpp:283             check_signed         ] **Application does not have a valid signature; Secure Enclave support disabled**
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.681 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:422           plugin_initialize    ] configured http to listen on 127.0.0.1:8888
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.681 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/keosd/stop
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.681 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:486           plugin_startup       ] start listening for http requests
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.682 thread-0  wallet_api_plugin.cpp:73      plugin_startup       ] starting wallet_api_plugin
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.682 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/create
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.682 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/create_key
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.682 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/get_public_keys
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.682 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/import_key
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.682 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/list_keys
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.682 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/list_wallets
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.682 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/lock
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.682 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/lock_all
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.682 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/open
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.682 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/remove_key
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.682 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/set_timeout
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.682 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/sign_digest
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.682 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/sign_transaction
    info  2019-01-15T18:38:20.682 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:554           add_handler          ] add api url: /v1/wallet/unlock
```

I'm unable to run nodeos as well.

If I uninstall eosio and reinstall it, I get the exact same errors.

Originally I was able to run keosd & nodeos and produce some blocks.  The troubles started for me when nodeos was shut down improperly.  I've also tried deleting the eosio/data folder to restart block creation.

What am I missing?  Why can't I run these programs?

Answer (score 1):

Matt Witherspoon from the eos developers telegram channel was able to provide an answer: without a valid mac app store signature, keosd can't use the Secure Enclave. block.one doesn't provide a signed keosd, so you can ignore that error.